# How to make panels move left and right in extjs

Tags: extjs4, panel

I have implemented 2 panels through ExtJS and added one button to viewport.
on click of button i wrote jquery for hide and show,it is moving panels top and bottom,
How to make these panels to move left and right .
Can you please provide me the solution..

Thanks & Regards,
Sathya

Comment: I mean i have added panel1,panel2 and button in viewport .Using Sencha ExtJS 4.2.0

Comment: Try understand [Ext.util.Animate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Animate)